# Wrong .yml format in "Stellaris" game

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I want to parse yaml files that contain localization for "Stellaris". But all the time i have an error

```
"yaml mapping values are not allowed here"
```

I use **pyyaml**.
The main problem is that all the localization files in game have lines like this:

```
trait_ruler_immortal:0 "Immortal"
```

But in yaml documentation and forums i can see that we have to make 'space' after a colon. I dont understand what this "0" symbol means.
Interesting that game doesnt have any problems with parsing this files.
Maybe this is special yaml format?

EDIT:

More code:
l_english:
crisis.2087.desc_psionic_synth:0 "A small number"
EXTSYNTH_DIVINE_SPARK: "Divine Spark"
EXTSYNTH_START_AT_3:0 "§GLeaders from this species start at skill level 3§!"

Comment: The value you give is actually a valid YAML scalar. Since there is no space after the colon, the whole line is parsed as content (quotes are parsed as content unless the scalar starts with them). Can you show us more of the YAML file so that we can reproduce the error?

Comment: Added. EXTSYNTH_START_AT_3:0, EXTSYNTH_CAN_PRODUCE_NANITES:0, etc.

Comment: Note: As a file from a commercial game, this content is protected by copyright and it might not be the best idea to dump it on pastebin. A small except should be fine, but IANAL.

Comment: Maybe but this is code from mode localization. Ok. i`ll delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is invalid YAML according to the spec. It may well be that Stellaris does some preprocessing on it before it gives the file to the YAML loader. We can only guess what happens here.

The best shot parsing it is probably loading it to string and then doing

```py
input.replace(":0 ", ": ")
```

before parsing it.

Comment: Thank for help.In official forum i got this result: "IIRC the 0 (or a higher number) is used internally for translators to know when a string needs a new translation. You can just put a 0 or any other number there if you make new strings.". Using 'replace' seems to be a good solution.